# Add percentage to SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, percentage

I have a table in my SSRS report.

[image]

As you can see to the right hand side I have a column called %.
How can I calculate this?
The only way I know how is to take the [Count(AssetId)on the row above the total line (this is Textbox11) and divide it by the [Count(AssetId)in the total row (this is Textbox8). So basically how do I dive two text boxes together?

[image]

So basically I want to divide the 573 by 1025 (my total) in order to get a percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression in the `%` column:

```
=Count(Fields!AssetId.Value)/Count(Fields!AssetId.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Change `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset.

Let me know if this can help you.